# Groovy - Strings with "$"

Tags: groovy

Is there any way to by pass "$" keyword at runtime 
eg
**`println $anish`**

output will be
**`$anish`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with a backslash println \$anish

Comment: without baclslas is this possible via any runtime parameter

Answer (score 4):

Either use single quoted strings:

```
println '$anish'
```

Or escape the dollar as Tom suggests

```
println "\$anish"
```

Comment: is there any other way at runtime can i tell groovy to ignore the $ sign

Comment: i have a scenario where i recieved a file from a webservice that file contain "$" character in it, while invoking groovy on that file it throws error, becoz of $ is not in quote or backslash, i have to replace it manually using sed command , is there any way to change the "$" sign in single quaote or put backslash it @ runtime or during runtime if we can tell to to groovy to bypass it is this possoble

Comment: What do you mean "invoking groovy on that file"? This sort of detail really should be in your questions rather than them being an elaborate fishing trip for the people trying to help you...